# Check if div ID exists in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have same php to generate HTML in 2 ocasions:

1. Generate a link with `target="_new"`;
2. Generate a link without target property.

The only way that I have to differentiate both of them is to create the parent div as different ID (eg: `<div id="new">` for the 1st, '' for the 2nd.

Is there any way to check if has some `#new` in html and them set target?

Here's the way that I've tried so far:

```
<?php $new = $html->find("#new"); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $item->getPrimaryLink()->getUrl(); ?>" <?php if (is_object($new)): ?> target="_new" <?php else : ?> <?php endif; ?> >
```

Comment: @all call it a hunch but I think this is part of a Joomla template rather than any specific *DOM* parser - though maybe it does use a specific parser itself?

Comment: @Emissary love it when OP's disappear leaving us to ponder.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat well let's not dwell on it too much - it could have just have easily been another code-dump *"question"* with no explanation...

Comment: @Emissary "Heh, look at this user3086817 with only `8` reputation doing a question like this, let me assert that he's probably a newbie with 86438 Joomla! sites and he even can't use a specific parser itself!". Badly hunch!

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at friend but that sounds awfully facetious - The point is that if you want a detailed answer you need to put detail into the question - this includes the environment and tool set that you are working with.  If you are using Joomla then it would do you well to mention it and `tag` it in the first place and not take it personally when people critique the *quality* of your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following [HTMLDOMPARSER](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) then you can follow:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$is_new_exist=false;
if($html->find('div#new'))
$is_new_exist=true;
```

And now you can use that flag for your checking

For further query please checkout [HTMLDOMPARSER](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I would presume you would be able to use something like

```
$new = $html->find("#new");
if ($new) {
    echo something
} else {
    echo something else
}
```

Based on the assumption you are using domdocument or a html parser.

You would not use `target` however but rather do something like `<a href="#new"` or if it were on another page `<a href="somepage.php#new"`