# How to check the existence of any HTML element using a PHP condition?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

On a WordPress website, how can I check the existence of any HTML element (with ID or class) using a PHP condition?

### This ticket solution didn't work in my case. [Check if div ID exists in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882327/check-if-div-id-exists-in-php)

Anyway, I've tried with this code:

```
$new = $html->find("#banner_id");
if($new){
    echo "Exists";
} else {
    echo "Not Exists";
}
```

But this resulted in the following error:

[image: error-image]

Comment: So your `$html` variable is null, and not an object. How are you creating it? What are you expecting it to be?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about this $html variable, I thought it would be pre defined any object or anything! That's why didn't investigate about this. Anyway, what should I do now to make it working? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if div ID exists in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882327/check-if-div-id-exists-in-php)

Comment: That didn't solve my case.

Answer (score 1):

I found your $html variable is null you need to create object before start to find the element by id

```
 $html = new simple_html_dom(); // Create a DOM object
 Method - 1:  $html->load_file('path-to-file/example.html');   // Load HTML from a HTML file   
 Method - 2:  $html->load_file('http://www.yourdomainname.com/');// Load HTML from an URL
 Method - 3:  $html->load('<html><body><div id="banner_id">All the Besttttt!</div></body></html>'); // Load HTML from a string
```

Either use any method from above list then start to find it.

```
$main = $html->find('div[id=banner_id]',0);// Find the element where the id is equal to a particular value
```

---

Complete code

---

```
$html->load('<html><body><div id="banner_id">All the Besttttt!</div></body></html>');// Load HTML from a string
$divdata= $html->find('div[id=banner_id]',0);// Find the element where the id is equal to a particular value
```

For more detail please have a look here http://www.gurutechnolabs.com/php-simple-html-dom-parser-script/

Comment: Hi, May be I couldn't use it on the proper way or it the process didn't work properly.

I've used the following code then getting another error.

`$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<html><body><div class="div2"><a id="banner">Sample Link</a></div></body></html>');
$divdata= $html->find('a[id=banner]',0);`

Error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'simple_html_dom' not found in /home/showhan/sites/public_html/phplearning/index.php:30 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/showhan/sites/public_html/phplearning/index.php on line 30`

Comment: Yes found that there is simpl_html_dom file is not included just download that file form here https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/?source=typ_redirect and include it , I hope this will solve your issue